# Is permission of typo3temp affect in fetching page of newsletter using direct mail?

Tags: typo3, newsletter

When i am trying to fetch pages under direct mail folder in TYPO3 backend, It gives following errors

The plain text content could not be fetched.
The HTML content could not be fetched.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error that most of the time shows up if you are missing your templates **include static** section.

Login to your TYPO3 Backend with administrator access. Next goto your, for example, root template. Select the "Includes"-tab and make sure the next "Include Static" are included:

```
Direct Mail Content Boundaries (direct_mail)
Direct Mail Plaintext (direct_mail)
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks, but i have already included this things in include static section.

Comment: This and doubler's answer solved my issues. +1s to both of you.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your server ip and domain to the `/etc/hosts` file if you are linux...if you are in windows to `\System32\drivers\etc`.

A deitalled description can be found here:

http://devbackyard.blogspot.pt/2012/10/direct-mail-typo3-content-could-not-be.html